# SWT Shell is not raised above in xfwm4

Tags: java, gtk, swt

I have problem with xfwm4. Using following code:

```
Shell s = windowVector.get(0).getShell();
s.setActive();
```

Shell window that is covered by other shells is not raised above. Using kwin (KDE window manager) it works correctly. Shell is created using following constructor:

```
shell = new Shell(mainShell, SWT.NO_TRIM | SWT.MODELESS);
```

In both cases SWT method:

```
OS.gdk_window_focus (window, OS.GDK_CURRENT_TIME);
```

is called but in xfwm4 shell get focus and is NOT raised above all other shell windows (in my application). Is this bug in xfwm4? Maybe some configuration issue or I am missig something.

EDIT:

I might be not precise. Shell that i try to setActive is "under" other child shells. Following code explains and simplfy what I am trying to achieve:

```
Shell mainShell = new Shell(Display.getDefault(), SWT.NO_TRIM);
mainShell.setBounds(0, 0, 300, 200);
mainShell.open();
final Shell shell1 = new Shell(mainShell, SWT.NO_TRIM | SWT.MODELESS);
shell1.setBounds(0, 0, 300, 200);
shell1.open();
Shell shell2 = new Shell(mainShell, SWT.NO_TRIM | SWT.MODELESS);
shell2.setBounds(0, 0, 300, 200);
shell2.open();
Thread thread = new Thread() {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
                Thread.sleep(2000);
                System.out.println("Raise shell1 above");
                shell1.setActive();
        }
        catch(InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
};
thread.start();
while( !mainShell.isDisposed()) {
    if( !Display.getDefault().readAndDispatch()) {
        Display.getDefault().sleep();
    }
}
Display.getDefault().dispose();
```

This code works correctly in kwin, in xfwm4 shell1 stays "under" shell2 and remains hidden.

Answer (score 0):

I can't speak about `xfwm4` specifically but yes, many window managers have some form of input stealing prevention.

You don't want any random application being allowed to steal your focus or force your attention away from what you are doing.

How they implement this behaviour differs between window managers however. Most should (ideally) allow the currently focused application to give focus to a newly created window of that application but I imagine not all do that.

Comment: I have multiple shells in one application. My shell gain focus correctly but z-order is not changed. According to SWT docs:
setActive()
          If the receiver is visible, moves it to the top of the drawing order for the display on which it was created (so that all other shells on that display, which are not the receiver's children will be drawn behind it) and asks the window manager to make the shell active

Comment: @Kuba The question is how it actually performs that raising. If it explicitly tries to raise the window or trusts the wm to do that on focus change or "presentation" request. I don't know that a wm can prevent an explicit raise (but I haven't worked with X stuff in a while so I'm a bit rusty) but I know that the response to a "present" request is entirely up to the wm.

Comment: @Kuba The issue may also be as simple as `xfwm4` not doing "click to raise" while `kwin` is doing that. Also, I assume the window is actually visible when you call that function (for whatever "visible" means in that context).

Comment: Unfortunately in this case this is not the solution. I've tried almost every option in ~/.config/xfce4/xfconf/xfce-perchannel-xml/xfwm4.xml none helped.