# Focus restore on JFace dialog close

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

In an Eclipse plugin with jFace dialogs I need to open a modal dialog on top of another modal dialog. The problem is when I close the second dialog (the one on the top) the focus is not restored to the first dialog. Instead the Eclipse workbench has focus.

This is the code I'm using as an example:

```java
    public class SampleHandler extends AbstractHandler {

        @Override
        public Object execute(ExecutionEvent event) throws ExecutionException      {
            IWorkbenchWindow window = HandlerUtil.getActiveWorkbenchWindowChecked(event);

            MessageDialog dialog = new MessageDialog(window.getShell(), "My Title 1", null, "My message 1", MessageDialog.ERROR,
                new String[] { "First", "Second", "Third" }, 0);
            dialog.setBlockOnOpen(false);
            dialog.open();


            MessageDialog dialog2 = new MessageDialog(window.getShell(), "My Title 2", null, "My message 2", MessageDialog.ERROR,
                new String[] { "First", "Second", "Third" }, 0);
            dialog2.open();

            return null;
        }
    }
```

When the user closes dialog2, dialog should take back focus.. It should be the normal behaviour if I'm not wrong here.

The only way of making it to work (that I have found...) is to make these changes:

```java
    MessageDialog dialog2 = new MessageDialog(dialog.getShell(),..
```

**and call this after dialog2.open() returns.**

```java
    PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getActiveWorkbenchWindow().getShell().setFocus();
```

But I don't understand why this works, and I should remerber to call this every time I open a dialog...
Any idea why I'm getting this? Can be a bug or I'm doing something wrong??

Comment: Using `dialog.getShell()` is the correct thing to do. I don't think SWT/JFace makes any guarantee about what will happen if you open two dialogs at once using the same parent shell.

Comment: Thankyou @greg-449 for the answer. I will use the shell of the already opened dialog. But I need to call setFocus() on the active shell in any case, to get that shell "in front".
Calling dialog.getShell() doesn't work, but the problem here is that I **need to call something**. The focus should come back to `dialog` automatically..

Comment: I have found out that this is a problem with the window manager and SWT widgets! 
Look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25892951/swt-shell-is-not-raised-above-in-xfwm4

I'm using XFCE with xfwm as window manager, **I tried with kwin and works perfectly**!
I'm afraid that nothing can be done to workaround this, except change the window manager..